# How can I exclude a port from macports upgrade outdated?

Tags: macos, package-management, macports

I want to update all my outdated ports, but as `libgcc-devel` takes upwards of 3 hours to build, I want to exclude it. The tip I read on the internet is applying logical operators. So I run

```
$ sudo port upgrade outdated and not libgcc-devel
--->  Computing dependencies for libgcc-devel
--->  Building libgcc-devel
...
```

To my frustration, it silently ignores that part of the command. I tried with `*gcc*` as well, to no avail.
What is the correct syntax for this?

The documentation states that this works with `uninstall`, but does not mention `upgrade`.

```
$ sudo port uninstall inactive and not <portname>
```

Comment: I would run `port dependents libgcc-devel`. Do any outdated ports need `libgcc-devel`?

Comment: @fd0 You're right, that seems to have been it, should've thought of that. I did not expect any port to depend on it, as those that need it typically use `libgcc`, but since the tow are incompatible I must have done something to have them use that one.

Comment: Your idea using logical operators is good -- now you just need to combine it with pseudo-port expressions and you're done: `port upgrade outdated and not rdependentof:libgcc-devel`. If `libgcc-devel` is outdated, you might also want to exclude that explicitly, since `libgcc-devel` is not an rdependent of itself.

Comment: @neverpanic Thanks for the advice. I had this same problem with the `capstone` port on Mojave, where it wasn't upgrading properly for some reason. I was able to get what I needed by doing what you said. Specifically: `port upgrade outdated and not rdependentof:capstone and not capstone`